# Our logs showing a lot of SSH brute force attacks originating on Port 11

Tags: ssh, brute-force

this forum has been brilliant so far. Just wondering if I can get a bit more help:

Can I get some info on a large amount of SSH brute force attacks originating from port 11 on the external host over the past 1 month

Now I know that port number can be faked, but if it isn't, what possibly could be causing this? I've looked for some tools that use port 11, but no joy

If you have any ideas on what it is, or how I can get more info, I'll be extremely grateful

Comment: Can you be more specific about "SSH brute force attacks originating from port 11"? Do you have example log entries, are there patterns in the attacks, etc. That may help to fingerprint anything 'familiair'.

Comment: Hi Jan- I will have to sanitise the log entries before posting on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Source port numbers are normally chosen at random so as not to interfere with servers listening on "well-known" ports. If machine A is a client to machine B (e.g. B is your SSH server), then the kernel on A will normally choose a random free "high" port, because if it chooses port *N*, then this will prevent any potential connection from B to a server running on A and bound on port *N*.

However it is trivial to choose a specific source port; it is a matter of a simple `bind()` call prior to the `connect()`. For port values which are lower than 1024, on Unix systems, this requires `root` privileges, but we can assume that the attacker is `root` on his own machine. Why would an attacker do that ? Probably to fool badly-written firewall rules. Some sysadmins simply allow packets with low port values on the (mistaken) assumption that a low port can only be on the server side of a connection.

For the record, port 11 is for the `systat` service, an old-style way for sysadmins to gather some runtime system information on their machines.

Comment: Or the attacker is on a windows machine with no such low port restriction? Now I wonder how many more of us would have had to look up which abandoned service used that port.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. Luckily the client only allows certificate credentials as it is a public facing server, so it was protected

Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3):

SSH clients, and most anything else, randomize their source port. However, it's usually a high-number port. The attacker's brute-force tool probably just has 11 hard-coded as the source port.

Comment: That's what I was wondering. But I have generally not seen a hard coded port lower than 1024, but maybe it's just a fact- it was just a little suspicious that 80% of different occurrences of the SSH brute force attacks used the same port.

Thanks for the info

Comment: Thomas made a good point that it might be an attempt to deceive stupid firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

It can very well be that your attacker is using a home brew tool. This means he has written it himself.

If you want to protect your machine from these attacks you should try out [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net/) it automatically blocks offenders after a few tries on your SSH port.

Comment: Hi, we're recommending the client runs fail2ban, we'll see how that helps/

Thanks for the info

Answer (score -1):

The attacker is probably trying to get a list of processes running on your external facing host so that they can then start going after those.

http://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=11

Comment: Oh no, a time-traveling attacker from 1992. Next he's going to own fingerd.

Comment: I know some machines fingerd is still running on... No, I don't own them.

Comment: @ZachOfAllTrades that would only apply to destination port not source port which is set to port 11. And I doubt there are enough computers running systat to even bother attempting to find one.

Comment: Yeah, that service and another trojan use port 11, but as a destination and not a source!

Thanks all for the answers!